# curl ip address of load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, curl, azure-networking

I have an application running on a VM, that sits behind an internal load balancer in Azure. I can reach it locally on /api without any problem.
I have configured the rules for the load balancer to direct traffic coming from port 8001 to 443 on the VM. However, when I try to curl http:///api:8001, it doesn't reach the VM.

How would you curl using a private IP to reach the application that is on the VM?

Comment: Have you configured firewalls rules?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a curl from a VM which is not part of the backend pool. The curl URL should be http://InternalLBIP/api:8001 . Also make sure you are using the correct protocol as I see you are translating 8001 to 443.

LB will only forward the packet to the backend pool when the Probes are healthy. Make sure your Probe is healthy.